# How to deploy dependent contracts with Ethereum Wallet

Tags: mist, contract-deployment, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have two contracts (i.e. `contractA`, `contractB`) located in different files (i.e, contractA.sol, contractB.sol) to deploy. The `contractB` is dependent on `contractA`. In contractB.sol,

```
import "contractA";
```

The `contractA` has been deployed successfully to Testnet with Ethereum Wallet by putting source of `contractA` in tab "SOLIDITY CONTRACT SOURCE CODE". When `contractB` was deployed, Ethereum Wallet complained:

```
Could not compile source code. Source "contractA.sol" not found.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just include the source for contractA in the tab with contractB's source. For instance:

```
contract A {
    ...
}

contract B {
    A a;
    function B(address _a) {
        a = A(_a);
    }
    ....
}
```

When you compile and go to deploy, just make sure you select B. (And make sure that the A code is **identical** to what you've already deployed.)

That said, the command line Solidity compiler handles import instructions quite nicely, as does the Javascript implementation. (See https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js)