# Trying to reference mortal.sol in standard ethereum library

Tags: solidity, inheritance

I am trying to reference mortal.sol in the standard ethereum library. I have deployed mortal.sol under my main test account. However I get the error source not found. What I tried was:

import "https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/std/mortal.sol"

Then I have a contract set up like:

contract foo is mortal {

somestuff;
}

what do I need to do to reference a Mortal contract that is deployed already on the chain?

I have looked at some posts but cannot seem to figure out. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer. but I have been using the Solidity compiler in the Ethereum Wallet UI. I was able to solve the problem by using the post:

[How to deploy dependent contracts with Ethereum Wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10009/how-to-deploy-dependent-contracts-with-ethereum-wallet)

Basically, I pasted the code I wanted to compile including the contract Mortal that I had already deployed but did not deploy Mortal again.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot import a remote dependency into your local contract. You can remap the reference to a local directory, but you still need to clone the dependent contracts in order to compile your contract.

From the [Solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/layout-of-source-files.html?highlight=import#use-in-actual-compilers):

> When the compiler is invoked, it is not only possible to specify how to discover the first element of a path, but it is possible to specify path prefix remappings so that e.g. github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/library is remapped to /usr/local/dapp-bin/library and the compiler will read the files from there.
>
> So as an example, if you clone github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/ locally to /usr/local/dapp-bin, you can use the following in your source file:
>
> `import "github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/library/iterable_mapping.sol" as it_mapping;`
>
> and then run the compiler as
>
> `solc github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/=/usr/local/dapp-bin/ source.sol`